# Perl is hanging, possibly related to print

Tags: perl, read-eval-print-loop, genetics

I'm at a loss on this one. I have a perl script that: 
1. processes Genbank files (which are very messy and inconsistent) in a directory (example GBK file here: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/archive/old_genbank/Bacteria/Acetobacter_pasteurianus_IFO_3283_01_uid31129/AP011121.gbk) 
2. splits each file by the genes
3. in a foreach loop, gets relevant information about each gene
4. prints the information about that gene at the end of each loop
Problem: it keeps hanging randomly in the middle of specific files, but there is nothing obviously different about them or about the gene that they stop on, and the files are scattered throughout the >72K total files. When it hangs the output printed to the command line is several loops (genes) ahead of the output printed to the file (see picture).
Troubleshooting: the variables it stops on are different for different files, it sometimes hangs mid-printing a variable, the RAM/CPU usage is low, when it hangs it still uses memory/CPU, it hangs both on windows (with latest version of strawberry perl) and linux (flux HPC) systems, there is nothing wrong with the output (since the command line output is ahead of the file output, I can see that it can and does process the gene that it hangs on during the print to file).

Sorry for the length of the code, I am a microbiologist so it isn't as clever/shorthand as some of the code I see on stackoverflow (also Genbank files are very inconsistent in format/language so I have to program around that). I'm happy to implement other code suggestions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

##### open output files #####
$GBKINFO    = 'L:\NCBI_DAT\GBFF\Bacteria_tablist.txt';
open(GBKINFO,'>', $GBKINFO)||die "unable to open $GBKINFO:$!\n";
$debug      = 'L:\NCBI_DAT\GBFF\Bacteria_debug.txt';
open(DEBUG,'>', $debug)||die "unable to open $debug:$!\n";
$GBKGENOMES = 'L:\NCBI_DAT\GBFF\Bacteria_taxonomy.txt';

##### load taxonomy hash #####
$taxons = 'R:\1_Downloads\taxa.Bacteria.dat';
open(TAXONS, $taxons) || die "unable to open $taxons: $!\n";
my %TAXhash; 
while(<TAXONS>){ 
(my $orgID, my $phylog)=split('\t',$_); $TAXhash{$orgID}=$phylog;}
close(TAXONS);

##### load protIDs hash #####
$protid = 'R:\1_Downloads\geneinfo.Bacteria.dat';
open(PROTID, $protid) || die "unable to open $taxons: $!\n";
my %IDhash; 
while(<PROTID>){ 
(my $prot, my $ID)=split('\t',$_); 
$prot =~ s/\s//g; $ID =~ s/\n//g;
$IDhash{$prot}=$ID;}
close(PROTID);

##### get genbank files #####
my $dir = 'L:\NCBI_DAT\GBFF\Bacteria';
die unless opendir DIR, $dir;
foreach my $file (readdir DIR) {
    $/="\n//\n";
    next if $file eq '.' or $file eq '..';
    $gbk = $dir.'/'.$file;
    $gbk =~ s/\//\\/g; 
    $gbk =~ /GCA_(\d+)/;

#######  open .gbk file and split contigs   #######
if(-f $gbk && $gbk =~ /\.(gbk|gbff)/ && $gbk !~ /gz$/ ){
    open(GBK, $gbk) || die "unable to open $gbk: $!\n";
    $i=1; $count =0; 

    while(<GBK>){
        $BIG=$_;
        $BIG =~ s/[\@<>\%\n]//g;
        if($BIG =~ /(\s+CDS\s{5}|\s+\S*RNA\s{5})/){

            # Get Phylogeny
            $BIG =~ ~ /db_xref\=\"taxon:(\d+)/; 
            $taxID=$1; $count = 1;
            $BIG =~ /ORGANISM\s+(.*?)\s+(\w+\;.*?)\./; 
            $SPECIES = $1; $PHYLOGENY = $2;
            $PHYLOGENY =~ s/\(.*?\)//g;  $PHYLOGENY =~ s/[^\w\;]//g; 
            $taxonomy = $TAXhash{$taxID}; 
            if($taxonomy =~ /\w/){ 
                $taxonomy =~ s/(\s+\;$|\s+$|\s+\;\s+$)//g; 
                $PHYLOGENY = $taxonomy;} 
            else{$PHYLOGENY=$PHYLOGENY."\;".$SPECIES;} 
            $PHYLOGENY =~ s/[\t\n]//g;

            if($PHYLOGENY =~ /Bacteria/i){$org="B";}
            elsif($PHYLOGENY =~ /Virus/i){$org="V";}
            elsif($PHYLOGENY =~ /Fungi/i){$org="F";}
            elsif($PHYLOGENY =~ /Archaea/i){$org="A";}
            elsif($PHYLOGENY =~ /Chordata/i){$org="C";}
            elsif($PHYLOGENY =~ /(Viridiplantae|Stramenopiles|Rhodophyta)/i){$org="P";}
            elsif($PHYLOGENY =~ /Eukaryota/i && $org !~ /[ABCFHPRV]/){$org="I";}
            else{$org="U";}

            # Print Phylogeny
            open(GENO, '>>', $GBKGENOMES)||die "unable to open $GBKGENOMES:$!\n";
            print GENO "$taxID\t$PHYLOGENY\n"; close(GENO);

            # get genome seq ###
            $BIG =~ /ORIGIN(.+)/;
            $GenomeSeq=$1;
            $GenomeSeq =~ s/[^a-z]//ig;
            $GenomeSeq = uc($GenomeSeq);
            if(length($GenomeSeq)<100){next;} # eg Bos Taurus genome had no gene seqs

            # split file by genes 
            $BIG =~ /VERSION\s{5,}(\w.*?)\s/; $Accession = $1;
            $BIG =~ s/(\s+gene\s{5})/\%$1/g;
            $BIG =~ s/(\s+[a-z]RNA\s{5})/\%$1/g;
            $BIG =~ s/(\s+CDS\s{5})/\%$1/g;
            $BIG =~  s/order\((\d+)\W*.*?\W(\d+)\)+/$1\.\.$2/g;
            $BIG =~  s/join\((\d+)\W*.*?\W(\d+)\)+/$1\.\.$2/g;
            @genes = split("\%",$BIG); $junk=shift(@genes);

            # get gene info 
            foreach(@genes){ 
                $gline = $_;
                if($gline =~ /^\s+gene\s+/){next;}

                # get gene type
                if($gline =~ /\s+CDS\s+[\dc]/)      {$type = "Protein";}
                elsif($gline =~ /\s\/pseudo/)           {$type = "Pseudo";}
                elsif($gline =~ /\s+\S*[^mr]RNA\s{5}/){$type = "ncRNA"; 
                    $gline =~ /\/note\=\".*\;*(.*)\"/; $LOC=$1; 
                    if($LOCUS !~ /\w/){$LOCUS=$LOC;}}
                elsif($gline =~ /\s+rRNA\s{5}/)     {$type = "rRNA";}
                elsif($gline =~ /\s+tRNA\s{5}/)     {$type = "tRNA";}
                else{next;}

                # get gene names and ids
                if($gline =~ /\/note\=\".*(COG\d\d\d\d)/)       {$COG = $1; $COG =~ s/\s//g;}   else{$COG ='';}
                if($gline =~ /\/note\=\".*:(K\d\d\d\d\d)/)  {$KO = $1; $KO =~ s/\s//g;} else{$KO ='';}
                if($gline =~ /\/locus_tag\=\"(.*?)\"/)      {$LOCUS = $1; $LOCUS =~ s/\s//g;}   else{$LOCUS ='';}
                if($gline =~ /\/protein_id\=\"(.*?)\"/)     {$ProtID = $1; $ProtID =~ s/\s//g;} else{$ProtID ='';}
                if($gline =~ /\/product\=\"(.*?)\"/)            {$Product = $1;}    else{$Product ='';}
                if($gline =~ /\/gene\=\"(.*?)\"/)               {$GName = $1;}  else{$GName ='';}
                if($gline =~ /\/inference\=\".*(RF\d+)\"/)  {$Rfam = $1;}   else{$Rfam ='';}
                if($gline =~ /\/translation\=\"([\w\s]+)\"/)    {$AAseq = $1; $AAseq =~ s/\s//g;}   else{$AAseq ='';}

                # get gene seq and coords                   
                if($gline =~/(RNA|CDS)\s+(\d+)\D*\.\.\D*(\d+)/){ 
                    if($2>$3){$start = $3; $end = $2;} 
                    else{$start = $2; $end = $3;}
                    $strand = "\+"; $seq= substr $GenomeSeq, $start-1, $end-$start+1;}
                elsif($gline =~/(RNA|CDS)\s+compl\S*?(\d+)\D*\.\.\D*(\d+)/){
                    if($2>$3){$start = $3; $end = $2;}
                    else{$start = $2; $end = $3;} 
                    $strand = "\-"; $seq= substr $GenomeSeq, $start-1, $end-$start+1;
                    $seq =~ tr/atgcrykmbvhdATGCRYKMBVHD/tacgyrmkvbdhTACGYRMKVBDH/; 
                    $rseq=reverse($seq); $seq=$rseq;}
                else{print DEBUG "no coords $gline\t$gbk\n"; next;}

                $seq=uc($seq); $Glen = length($seq); $coords = "$start\.\.$end";
                if($Glen < 5){print DEBUG "gene length issue $gline\t$gbk\n"; next;}

                # get gene IDs
                print "prot id $ProtID and $gbk\n";
                $IDS = $IDhash{$ProtID}; $IDS =~ s/\n//g; $IDS =~ s/.*\&//; $Func = ''; $DATname = '';
                if($IDS =~ /\#/ ){($DATname, $Func) = split("\#", $IDS); $Func =~ s/(\s+$|^\s+)//;} 
                if($Func !~ /$COG/ && $COG =~ /COG\d\d\d\d/){$Func = $COG."\@".$Func;}
                if($Func !~ /$KO/ && $KO =~ /K\d\d\d\d\d/){$Func = $KO."\@".$Func;}
                $Func =~ s/(\@$|^\@)//g;

                # fix gene name issues
                if($GName =~ /((hypothetical|uncharacterized|conserved|predicted)\s+protein|unknown function|scaffold|contig)/i || length($GName)<3 || $GName !~ /\w/){
                       if(length($Product)>length($GName)   && $Product !~ /((hypothetical|uncharacterized|conserved|predicted)\s+protein|unknown function|scaffold|contig)/i){$GName=$Product;}
                    elsif(length($DATname)>length($GName)   && $DATname !~ /((hypothetical|uncharacterized|conserved|predicted)\s+protein|unknown function|scaffold|contig)/i){$GName=$DATname;}
                else{ if($type =~ /(protein|pseudo)/i){$GName = "Uncharacterized protein";} else{$GName = "Uncharacterized gene";}}}                
                $GName =~ s/([\;\,\.\@\<\>\%\|]|\(.*\))//g; $GName =~ s/(\s$|^\s)//g; $GName =~ s/\s+/_/g;
                if($LOCUS !~ /\w/){$LOCUS = $Accession."&".$coords;}

                $FINAL = "$LOCUS\t$ProtID\t$GName\t$type\t$Glen\t$strand\t$taxID\t$org\t$Func\t$AAseq\t$seq"; $FINAL =~ s/\n//g;
                if($LOCUS =~ /\w/){print GBKINFO "$FINAL\n";}

            } # foreach gene
                last;
            } # if big matches protein
            else{$i++; print "no protein $i\n"; next;}
        } # close while gbk
        close(GBK)||die "unable to close GBK:$!\n"; #just added to check it is closing

        if($count==0){ print "no genes unlinked $gbk\n"; unlink $gbk or warn    "Could not unlink $gbk: $!"; next;}
    } # closes 1st if for getting genomes
} # closes 1st foreach file

close(GBKINFO);
close(DEBUG);
```

[Image showing command line print is ahead of print to file and memory use is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wlFt.jpg)

Comment: When someone complains that print is freezing, they are usually mistaken, fooled by buffering. You can disable buffering by using `$fh->autoflush`

Comment: If a print is truly freezing, it's because you are writing to a pipe and the buffer is full. The pipe's reader needs to read some data before the write can complete.

Comment: Is there any change if the output is directed to a file? Or if the settings of command prompt are changed as suggested in this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/1053104/544510)

Comment: Two suggestions: subroutines and perltidy.  1. Your code is too long to fit onto one 40-line page, making it hard to grok what is going on.  Splitting it up will make it easier to deal with and to debug.  2. Running your code through perltidy will make it much easier for others to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I tried flushing the buffer using both the general $|=1; which didn't work with all the nested FHs, and then the FH specific one using:
      select((select(FH), $|=1)[0]);
     It helped me find out where it was hanging... one regex not meshing well with the mess of some gbk files. bad regex  ->   $gline =~ //note\=\".*\;*(.*)\"/;